# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition only return each 100 m

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

I am using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition in my react native project to paint a path on a map while the user is moving. I noticed that the return frequency is quite low for this function. I taught it was the frequency at least, when I tested using the iOS emulator and the "freeway drive" mode in the gps emulator. Now when I tested with "city run" instead, I can see that the return frequency of the position is not dependent on some time interval, but instead on a distance... The function is returning its position once each 100 meters, no matter how long it took for the position to change that much.

Why is it like this? Is this a expected behaviour? I don't know if it has to do with the iOS emulator or with my code, but I would really like the position to be more precise, I want it to return as often as possible.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { region } = this.state;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.setState({position});
        },
        (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) => {
        var { distanceTotal, record } = this.state;
        this.setState({lastPosition});
        if(record) {
            var newLatLng = {latitude:lastPosition.coords.latitude, longitude: lastPosition.coords.longitude};

            this.setState({ track: this.state.track.concat([newLatLng]) });
            this.setState({ distanceTotal: (distanceTotal + this.calcDistance(newLatLng)) });
            this.setState({ prevLatLng: newLatLng });
        }
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0});
}
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

There's an option you can set that is called `distanceFilter` which you set the accuracy in meters. It's stated in the [documentation for geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) but not explained what it does or the default value. If you take a look at the source code at [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e1577df1fd70049ce7f288f91f6e2b18d512ff4d/Libraries/Geolocation/RCTLocationObserver.m) the default is set to **100** meters, which explains your behavior.

If you want 1 meter accuracy you set the options as:
`{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1}`